# how to use node js to combine data from two jsons

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to merge data from two tables and then send the result as the response.

I'm new to nodejs and lambda and I'm unable to figure out how I can merge json data from both scan calls and send it as the response.

If I uncomment the callback then response for only one table is sent.

My code is below, can someone please help in completing it

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = function(event, ctx, callback) {

var params=  {
       TableName:'x',
       FilterExpression:'SessionId = :SessionId',
ExpressionAttributeValues:{ ":SessionId" : 'ca47a131'},
};


var params1=  {
    TableName:'y',
    FilterExpression:'sessionid = :SessionId',
    ExpressionAttributeValues:{ ":SessionId" : 'ca47a131'},
};

docClient.scan(params, onScan);
docClient.scan(params1, onScan1);

function onScan(err, data){
    if(err){
        callback(err, null);
    }else{

        //callback(null, data);
   }
}
function onScan1(err, data){
    if(err){
        callback(err, null);
    }else{

        //callback(null, data);
   }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to JavaScript asynchronous callbacks (aka [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/)).

Fortunately, the [AWS SDK supports promises](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html) so you can use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for multiple promises to be resolved. When that happens, merge the JSON results and return the merged result via the Lambda function's callback() method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following modification to the code so that you can send the response in a single callback.

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = function(event, ctx, callback) {

var params=  {
       TableName:'x',
       FilterExpression:'SessionId = :SessionId',
ExpressionAttributeValues:{ ":SessionId" : 'ca47a131'},
};

var params1=  {
    TableName:'y',
    FilterExpression:'sessionid = :SessionId',
    ExpressionAttributeValues:{ ":SessionId" : 'ca47a131'},
};

docClient.scan(params, onScan);
docClient.scan(params1, onScan1);

var firstResultData = false;
function runAfterBothCallbacks(data){
  if(!firstResultData){
     firstResultData = data;
  }else{
     // Combine firstResultData with data and return in the callback
     callback(null,{ dataX: firstResultData, dataY: data });
     // Note: The order of scan and scan1 result coming cannot be guaranteed so, dataX can be the results of scan or scan1. If you can identify the result based on the scan, either pass it as another parameter to the runAfterBothCallbacks method or identify the scan based on data result (If possible).
  } 

}

function onScan(err, data){
    if(err){
        callback(err, null);
    }else{
        runAfterBothCallbacks(data);
   }
}
function onScan1(err, data){
    if(err){
        callback(err, null);
    }else{
        runAfterBothCallbacks(data);
   }
}

}
```